# Codeigniter is giving me an error called "Disallowed Key Characters."

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, post

I have a input with name="exam[A+]". I have figured out that when I called `$this->input->post("exam")` it is giving me an error called "Disallowed Key Characters". I want to add + sign in my key characters. Here is the code in the system file.

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
    {
        if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
        {
            exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
        {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

How do I change the regular expression to add the + sign in the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex to allow `+`:

```
^[a-z0-9:_\/+-]+$
```

The main point is that the unescaped hyphen must be at the end of the character class.

Here is [a demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE3tM1/1).

Comment: Thank you, it has worked, if you don't mind can you please tell me how can I learn php regex. I know how regex works but I get confused I see regex written in PHP or javascript

Comment: To learn regular expressions to be able to edit such regexes, you need to visit http://www.regular-expressions.info/ (check the *Character classes* section), also have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html. To test your regexes, the best place is http://regex101.com, but there is also http://www.phpliveregex.com/.